# Cannot read property 'length' of null + "angular"?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-test

I am trying to count initial `li` and after fetching data from server (using unit test case), but I am getting **Cannot read property 'length' of null**

**My code:**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MockAppService } from './mock.service'
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>,
    component: AppComponent,
    service: AppService,
    debugEl:DebugElement,
    el:HTMLElement;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],

      providers: [{ provide: AppService, useClass: MockAppService }]

    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    service = TestBed.get(AppService);
     el = fixture.nativeElement;

    spyOn(service, 'getData').and.callThrough();

  }));

  afterEach(() => {
    //httpMock.verify();
  });

  describe('AppComponent onit test', () => {

        it('intial list item', async(() => {
                  debugEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('li'));
      expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('li').length()).toBe(0);
    }));
    it('should called appService getData method', async(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(service.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
    it('should return an Observable<User[]>', () => {
      const dummyUsers = [{
        userId: 10,
        id: 10,
        title: "post",
        body: "post"
      }];

      service.getData().subscribe(users => {
        console.log(users)
        expect(users.length).toBe(1);
        expect(users).toEqual(dummyUsers);
         expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('li').length()).toBe(1);

      });
    });
  })
});
```

code link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-w9towo?file=app%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but what's not clear about the error? You have a null property that you're getting the length of. Ensure it's not null before you do that.

Comment: before getting service response count `li` length and after receiving response `li` length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

query does not return an array, try to use queryAll to return an array instead of query
  here is the solution:

```
it('intial list item', async(() => {
   let liCount= fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('li'));
   expect(liCount.length).toBe(0);
}));
```

Comment: getting error `fixture.debugElement.query.all is not a function`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-w9towo?file=app%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

Comment: i updated the answer with the solution, it works for me here :)

Answer (score 0):

When you look at this documentation: https://angular.io/api/core/DebugElement

You will find that `DebugElement.query` method returns `DebugElement`

and the method `DebugElement.queryAll` method returns `DebugElement[]`

so `DebugElement.queryAll` will return an array of `DebugElement`

and in this case, since it's an array you can then apply `length` property to it.

So you have to use `DebugElement.queryAll` in order to test the length of the resulting array.